# How to aligning icon on right side of the screen when the screen size is small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, slick.js

In the picture below you can see my right arrow has gone off the screen when the screen size is small.  How can I fix this?

[image]

The arrows and carousel are aligned mostly using bootstrap's grid with a little bit of custom css.  It is easiest just to see it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvrm5bg/1/), but here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vcenter-parent">

        <div id="carouselParent" class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="carousel">
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 vcenter-child" style="float:left;">
            <a class="slick-prev">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x"> </i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11 vcenter-child hright" style="float:right;">
            <a class="slick-next">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x"> </i>
            </a>
        </div>    
    </div>           
</div>
```

**What I think is happening:**

The arrows are not bound by the width of the div.  For the left arrow this is ok because the arrow continues on to the right of the div, so really only the left padding is affecting the arrow's position.

[image]

However, on the right the arrow begins drawing after the left padding and continues right off the durping screen.

[image]

---

**Update:**
Yes my column math was wrong, it should have been an offset of 10 not 11.  However, the arrow now needs to be pushed to the right side.  Any ideas?

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvrm5bg/2/)

Comment: do you really need those `col-xs-1` classes? i think that is part of the problem

Comment: @cocoa I'm pretty sure I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bootstrap column offset was messing up column layout. Just move each of the arrows into a single size 12 column and float them left and right respectively.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vcenter-parent">
        <div id="carouselParent" class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="carousel">
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
                <div><img src="http://goo.gl/Z0AdfK"></img></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
         
        <div class="col-xs-12 vcenter-child" style="float:left;">
            <a class="slick-prev pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x"> </i>
            </a>
            <a class="slick-next pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x"> </i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row vcenter-parent" style="padding-top: 50px">
        <div class="col-xs-10.col-xs-offset-1">
            <div id="carouselText">
                <div><p>meow</p></div>
                <div><p>meow meow</p></div>
                <div><p>meeeeow meow</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                  
</div>
```